# Python 3.8 algebraic expression keeps returning 0.00

Tags: python-3.x, math

The following code keeps returning E1 = 0.00 when it should return E1 = 1.24. Most of the values are floats. The denominator is less than the numerator but from my understanding this shouldn't make a difference for Python 3 so I have no idea why it's not giving the correct answer. I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

```
import math

a1 = 11.88
period1 = 8.28
b = 19.7884
d = 1.73
g = 32.2
V = 675
Te = .28
Omega1 = 1/period1
w1 = V*Omega1
x1 = 1-(1/math.sqrt(1+w1**2*Te**2))
E1 = (1+(b*(d+x1*a1))/(25*d*(d+2*x1*a1)))/(1+((w1**2*a1**2*(1-x1))/2*V**2)**2)
```

Comment: Putting parentheses around the `2*V**2` part of the final line gives a result of about 1.24, so I think you mistranslated the formula at that point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo_, since the comment by @jasonharper resolves the issue `/(2*V**2))**2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like jasonharper's comment above, try to wrap your denominator in parentheses. Remember that the language evaluates some expression or formula by going in precedence order and then left to right. When you do

```
formula = x/y*z
```

this becomes x/y and then result*z, not x/(y*z).
So, putting the parenthesis around that part would resolve the issue:

```
E1 = (1+(b*(d+x1*a1))/(25*d*(d+2*x1*a1)))/(1+((w1**2*a1**2*(1-x1))/(2*V**2))**2)
```